# Can't access my component reference within inactive ngb-tabset

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm working on a ng-bootstrap component **ngb-tabset**. I have 2 tabs, each containing a child component.

```
<ngb-tabset #tabSet="ngbTabset" *ngIf="!user; else userView">
<ngb-tab id="child1" title="Child 1">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <mt-child-one></mt-child-one>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="child2" title="Child 2">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <mt-child-two></mt-child-two>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
<ng-template #userView>
<mt-user></mt-user>
</ng-template>
```

In my **component.ts** file, I'm trying to access the reference of these two child, like:

```
@ViewChild(Child1Component) child1Component: Child1Component;
@ViewChild(Child2Component) child2Component: Child2Component;
```

The problem I'm facing here is inside my **ngOnInit**, I can access my active tab component reference, but cannot get the reference for the inactive tab.

I tried with putting the inactive tab under **afterViewInit**, but still, it returns **undefined**. Can anyone guide what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `[destroyOnHide]="false"` to the `ngb-tabset` that will prevent Angular destroying a tab when it is hidden (source: [NgbTabset docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/api#NgbTabset) )

```
<ngb-tabset #tabSet="ngbTabset" *ngIf="!user; else userView" [destroyOnHide]="false">
  <ngb-tab id="child1" title="Child 1">
      ...
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="child2" title="Child 2">
      ...
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

This means you can then access both tabs (the visible and hidden) in the `ngAfterViewInit` of the component:

Note: you will need to use `AfterViewInit` rather than `OnInit`

Please see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzcvjf?file=app%2Ftabset-basic.html) for a demo (just open the console and you should see the following logging):

[image]